# How can I retain Word document formatting when pasting into a web form?

Tags: ms-word, text-formatting

When pasting a Word .doc or .rtf letter into a web form e.g into a textarea most of the document formatting (like bold or centering) is lost. Is there any way to do so without losing the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as long as you're using plain text areas: the textarea element is intended to carry only unformatted text.
If you need formatted text, you could try a javascript framework providing such.

AFAIK, [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/) has an editor widget that could contain formatted text.